# 'rmarkdown::render' not found error when knit

Tags: r, rstudio

After updated the R and Rstudio to latest version,
I even can not knit(default [knit] button) the default .rmd, both html and pdf.
I updated the rmarkdown and any other packages but still not working.

Error:

```
[1] 127
Warning message:
In system(paste0("rmarkdown::render \"", input, "\"")) : 
  'rmarkdown::render' not found
```

Version:

```
[1] "R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)"
> RStudio.Version()
$version
[1] ‘1.4.1717’
$release_name
[1] "Juliet Rose"
```

Comment: `rmarkdown::render` is not a system function. You should not be using `system()` to run it. That is R code. What exactly does the code you are trying to run look like? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!  I just new  a default rmd and run [knit] button like I always do.. It did well before I updated.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error right now because of a R version update. I solved it by updating tinytex.

> install.packages("tinytex")